# How to use sbt with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, sbt

Has anybody tried to setup sbt to work with Google App Engine? I dream about using development server auto-reloading after source changes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a quick demo you can clone or download what I have done [here](http://github.com/leolannenmaki/sbt-appengine-plugin-skeleton).

## A minimalistic [sbt-appengine-plugin](http://github.com/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin) example from scratch

**Clone the sbt-appengine-plugin from GitHub**

```
 cd mystuff
 git clone git://github.com/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin.git
 cd sbt-appengine-plugin
 sbt
```

**Publish the plugin locally so that you can use it in your own projects**

```
publish-local
exit
```

**Create a directory for a new project**

```
cd ..
mkdir sbt-appengine-plugin-test
cd sbt-appengine-plugin-test
sbt
```

**Configure the new project**

```
Project does not exist, create new project? (y/N/s) y
Name: sbt-appengine-plugin-test
Organization: com.example
Version [1.0]: 
Scala version [2.7.7]: 2.8.0.Beta1
sbt version [0.7.3]:
exit
```

**Tell sbt about the plugin you want to use**

```
mkdir project/build
mkdir project/plugins
nano project/build/project.scala
```

**project.scala**

```
import sbt._

class AppengineTestProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends AppengineProject(info)

nano project/plugins/plugins.scala
```

**plugins.scala**

```
import sbt._

class Plugins(info: ProjectInfo) extends PluginDefinition(info) {
  val a = "net.stbbs.yasushi" % "sbt-appengine-plugin" % "1.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

**Add a very simple servlet**

```
mkdir -p src/main/scala/com/example
nano -w src/main/scala/com/example/HelloWorld.scala
```

**HelloWorld.scala**

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.{HttpServlet, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse}

class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  override def doGet(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse$
    response.setContentType("text/plain")
    response.getWriter.println("Hello, world")
  }
}
```

**Add some more configuration files**

```
mkdir -p src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
nano -w src/main/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xm$
   version="2.5">
  <display-name>sbt-appengine-plugin usage example</display-name>
      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


nano -w src/main/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<!-- Replace this with your application id from http://appengine.google.com -$
  <application>hello-world</application>
  <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**And finally run sbt and start the project**

```
sbt

update
dev-appserver-start
```

**Point your browser to http://localhost:8080/ and you should see Hello, world**

```
dev-appserver-stop
```

To watch for changes in source files I have experimented a little with ~prepare-webapp after starting the server, but I haven't gotten it working properly.

Comment: In the servlet example, did you mean to put the dollar sign on the line that starts "override def doGet"? Surely, that is meant to be a close bracket?

Comment: you need to extend you project with the JRebel trait to get watch for changes working.

Comment: The Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin linked from this answer no longer exists unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [sbt-appengine-plugin](http://github.com/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin/tree/master) on Github that I'm trying to get to work right now.  I will post any progress.

Comment: The Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin linked from this answer no longer exists unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You will find an example by the author of the plugin here:
http://gist.github.com/377611

Especially in the plugins configuration, the setting of 1.1-SNAPSHOT (mentioned above) or 2.1-SNAPSHOT (mentioned in the sbt-apppengine-plugin README) did not work.

The example shows:

```
import sbt._

class Plugins(info: ProjectInfo) extends PluginDefinition(info) {
    val appenginePlugin = "net.stbbs.yasushi" % "sbt-appengine-plugin" % "2.0" from "http://github.com/downloads/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin/sbt-appengine-plugin-2.0.jar"
}
```

And this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a template project using sbt + appengine which can be used to get started:

https://github.com/mtkopone/sbt-scalatra-appengine-template

Also, instead of having to publish the sbt-appengine-plugin locally, you can use the following in Plugins.scala:

```
import sbt._
class Plugins(info: ProjectInfo) extends PluginDefinition(info) {
  lazy val appEngine = "net.stbbs.yasushi" % "sbt-appengine-plugin" % "2.1" 
    from "http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Yasushi/sbt-appengine-plugin/sbt-appengine-plugin-2.1.jar"  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example application describing how to set up a development environment and create an application using SBT and app engine. It also includes instructions on setting up JRebel to get the auto reloading you dream of.

See http://jeremys-scala-example.appspot.com/

It is for SBT 0.7 so its a little out of date.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new version of the sbt-appengine plugin which works with newer versions of SBT (0.10+) at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine. There's also a trivial sample app using it at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine.

I just converted a project that was created with Eclipse:

- Move scala files from src/ to src/main/scala.
- If you have java files, move them from src/ to src/main/java.
- Move war/ to src/main/webapp.
- If you have other files that should end up in WEB-INF/classes, put them in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/.

Answer (score 1):

Found this post in Google search. Since all provided examples are quite old I created two sample projects based on what I found online

- Sample GAE app written in Scala using [Scalatra 2.0.5](http://www.scalatra.org/), Scala 2.10.3 and SBT 0.13
  https://github.com/cppexpert/scalatra-google-app-engine-app
- Sample GAE app written in Scala using [Unfiltered 0.7](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html), Scala 2.10.3 and SBT 0.13
  https://github.com/cppexpert/sample-scala-google-app-engine-app