# App Engine doesn't find WEB-INF in WAR created by sbt

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, lift, sbt, web-inf

I'm trying to make a Lift app that I can run on App Engine and am managing the project with sbt. I have `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and package the project with `sbt project`. According to a [previous SO quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293491/how-to-use-sbt-simple-build-tool-with-google-app-engine), that should be all I need. However, I get this:

```
$ dev_appserver.sh target/scala_2.8.1/
2011-02-06 13:37:45.763 java[20355:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-02-06 13:37:45.765 java[20355:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Feb 6, 2011 12:37:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Supplied application has to contain WEB-INF directory.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.determineAppRoot(JettyContainerService.java:319)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:145)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
```

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I just figured out the problem after submitting the question. The following invocation of the dev server works: `dev_appserver.sh target/scala_2.8.1/webapp`